# How to access windows file system in Ubuntu Virtual Box

Tags: 14.04

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 VM on Virtual Box. My host OS is Win 7. How do i access the file systems in VM?

Is there a specific method to do it?

Answer (score 13):

You need to create a shared folder.

Open Ubuntu virtual machine settings. Select **Shared Folders** >  **Add new shared folder**.
Add the path of your Windows folder you need to access on your Ubuntu VM and click **OK**.

[image]

---

**Using Virtual Box Auto-mount option :**

In your Ubuntu machine, [install Virtual Box Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/a/693360/338915)

When it is done, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and add yourself to the `vboxsf` group (VirtualBox shared folder group) :

```
 sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```

Reboot your Ubuntu virtual machine and you will find your shared folder under `/media/sf_MySharedFolder`.

**Without Virtual Box Auto-mount option :**

In your Ubuntu machine, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and create the folder where your want to access your shared folder (I am going to create under my `home` directory:

```
mkdir shared
```

Then mount your shared folder :

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf $USER ~/shared/
```

Comment: Yes. i have created this but how do access it? Should i search in /mnt or /media?

Comment: @Prat did you checked **Auto-mount** ?

Comment: Yes. i had created with Auto-mount. And ran a find on the whole file system. But could not find it.

Comment: Ok. created a folder by name vboxsf on Win Desktop and added it to shared folder. Then tried to access it using the command sudo mount -f vboxsf $USER ~/shared/ . Sorry it did not work..

Comment: It says vboxsf file system not present

Comment: @Prat see my updated answer ;)

Comment: Aah... Did you installed [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://askubuntu.com/a/693360/338915) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31046/discussion-between-prat-and-hg8).

Comment: The auto-mount option works great!